# How to get context in a simple class without BuildContext in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I am using this package plugin `flutter_locales` for app localization. So check the current language code by using this is the code.

```
LocaleNotifier.of(context)!.locale!.languageCode;
```

Now problem is if i use this code inside in simple class which gives an error on "context".

```
class Service {
  var lang = LocaleNotifier.of(context)!.locale!.languageCode; // getting error on "context"
}
```

So how prevent this "context" error without BuildContext in Service class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply don't. You will need to pass in the `BuildContext context` to your `Service` class.

Try this:

```
class Service {
  final BuildContext context;

  Service(this.context);

  String get lang => LocaleNotifier.of(context)!.locale!.languageCode;
}
```

Then pass in the context when creating this class.